# como manejar la cargar de imagenes multiples cargando los filename a la bd

Tags: javascript

hola estoy utilizando una herramienta llamada ngx-dropzone en donde me permite subir multiples archivos de imagen de manera facil no hay problema con ello, mi problema radica en que el arreglo que sale de dropzone lo estoy guardando a mi servidor osea la imagenes y este las nombro y devuelvo el nombre del folder donde fueron guardadas, luego uso una funciona para publicar en donde creo capturo mi otra información titulo descripcion etc y el array nuevo con los nombres de las imagenes, este es el codigo que estoy usando..

el problema es que al enviarlo me sale vacio no se porque razón, haciendo un log del params veo que esta la información los nombres de mis imagenes.

```
  files: any = [];
  adsImgs: any = [];


  onSelect(event) {
    this.files.push(...event.addedFiles);
    console.log(event);
  }

  sendImage(){   
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) { 
      let f = this.files[i];
      let reader = new FileReader();      
      reader.readAsDataURL(f); 
      reader.onload = (e)=> {
        // console.log(e.target.result); base64
        let params = {
          archivo: e.target.result
        };
        this.servicios.enviarImg(params)
        .subscribe( (data) => {
          if(data['logger'] == true){
            this.adsImgs.push({img: data['filename'],folder: data['folder'],});
          }
        });  
      }
    }

  }

  
  onRemove(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.files.splice(this.files.indexOf(event), 1);
  }

  publicar(){
    if(this.files.length >= 1){
      this.sendImage();
      console.log("hay imgs");      
    }

    let params = {
      nuevo: true,
      titulo: this.inputTitulo,
      descripcion: this.editorText,
      adsImgs: this.adsImgs,
      estado: 1,
    }
    console.log(this.adsImgs);        
    this.servicios.SetAds(params)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      if (data["logger"] == true){
        this.router.navigate(['/'])
      } else {
      }
    });    
    
  }
```

el problema esta es que cuando envio parece no se carga la variable con mi areglo de nombre y me muestra de esta manera.
adsImgs: [];
y esta la cabecera de la solicitud enviada a mi servicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si hago un log del params tengo la informacion de adsImgs este es el console log del params

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me pueden echar una mano gracias.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado el metodo SetAds del servicio?

Comment: si vicente, puesto que el metodo estar guardando los demas campos como titulo, descripcion y de mas pero el addImgs llegs vacio []

Comment: Creo que las imágenes se suben al servidor en cuanto las agregas al `input type="file"` (seleccionando o arrastrando y soltando), independiente del evento `submit` del formulario. Normalmente subo las imágenes en una carpeta temporal y agrego checkboxes para seleccionarlas y, finalmente, al procesar el formulario, muevo esas imágenes a la carpeta pública, asociándolas con el registro correspondiente.

Comment: osea que de la forma que lo estoy haciendo esta mal, debo guardar todas las imagenes en una carpeta temporal luego guardar el arreglo en la bd y a la vez mover los archivos al folder definitivo ? y borrar el temporal.  no se puede hacer como lo estoy haciendo ?